# How similar are SVG and VML?

Tags: svg, vml

Ignoring the browser support issue (IE6, IE7, and IE8 only support VML; IE9 supports some SVG; the other major browsers support SVG) and deprecation of VML in favor of SVG, how similar are SVG and VML? I understand that they're not compatible, but they're both XML languages used to produce vector graphics. What's are the major differences between them, beyond syntax?

Comment: One of the differences: VML was supported by IE long before any of the other browsers supported either VML or SVG. ;-)  There are libraries that support both. You can use it as if working with SVG, and it will convert it to VML on the fly if in IE.

Comment: As per the current-day [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language), VML is considered a legacy format in the "Office Open XML" specification and [Microsoft has discontinued support as of IE 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801223(v=vs.85).aspx). So a dissimilarity is that vml's use is largely discouraged while svg is well supported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that might help you:

http://weborama.blogspot.com/2006/01/vml-svg-and-canvas.html

They're a bit outdated, but that's probably because VML is not **hot** anymore.

Comment: One of the links no long works. Make sure to cite or summarize relevant information.